# MongoDB get records with dates before a certian year

Tags: mongodb

I have data where I have a year stored as a number, and other data points stored as dates. something like this

```
{
    name: "bob",
    year_arrived: 2002,
    dob: 1995-06-06
}
```

if I want to get all the records where the dob is BEFORE the year_arrived minus 2 (meaning I want all before 2000 in the above example), how can I write that???

logically it's

```
WHERE $year(dob) < (year_arrived-2)
```

But for argument sake - let's pick a day of year such as July 1st
and get all records where dob < 2000-07-01

can I do something like

```
.find({ dob: { $lt: new ISOdate($concat:[(year_arrived-2),'-07-01']}) } })
```

I have tried that - with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `dob` is of type `Date`;

```
db.coll.find({
    "$expr": {
        "$lt": [ { "$year": "$dob" }, { "$subtract": ["$year_arrived", 2] } ]
    }
})
```

This will do `if (extract_year(dob) < (year_arrived - 2))` which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$gte": [
      { "$year": { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$dob" } } },
      { "$subtract": ["$year_arrived", 2] }
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: thx Ashh - 
i am reading this as '1995-06-06' Greater or equal to '2000' - how is this going to give me what Im looking for ? can you explain the query a bit.

Comment: @jpmyob `$gte` takes two expression for greater equal comparision. `$dateFromString` convert your date from string to date. `$year` will extract the year from the `$dateFromString` expression. and finally `$subtract` will subtract 2 years from `$year_arrieved` field.

Comment: @Ashh it should be $lt instead of $gte, right? We need to fetch the documents which have DOB year less than year_arrived-2.

Comment: @MrSSharma Either one. What ever OP needs can use the either `$lte` or `$gte` operator.

Comment: @jpmyob Your sample data shows that your date is in String and that is why I have converted it into date using `$dateFromString`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by parsing the year from DOB and comparing it with 'year_arrived'. The following query can get you the expected output.

```
db.data.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            $expr:{
                $gt:[
                    {
                        $subtract:[
                            "$year_arrived",
                            {
                                $toInt:{
                                    $substrBytes:[
                                        "$dob",
                                            0,
                                        {
                                            $indexOfBytes:["$dob","-"]
                                        }   
                                     ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                    ,2
                ]
            }   
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```